# New 18.04 install, Sublime Text 3 menu layout is broken

Tags: 18.04, gtk, menu, sublime-text

I installed 18.04 on a new laptop the other day and I'm trying to get it in shape to replace an older one. I installed Sublime Text 3, and while it *works* it has obvious layout problems:
[image]

The menus, again, *work* in that the little menu windows open up and the selections can be clicked, but clearly there's something basically wrong with the layout. The pop-down menus have no spacing around the edges, much as the main menu entries lack spacing.

I'm running the xfce4 desktop in an otherwise plain Ubuntu (i.e., not Xubuntu) installation, which is what I've been doing for many years now and which works fine on the older (16.04) laptop. I suspect that what's wrong (or missing) is some GTK setting or configuration, but I have not been able to figure out what's right on the old machine but wrong on the new one.

This is a dev build (3184) of Sublime 3, for what that's worth. Other applications seem to work without any weird menu layout problems.

*edit* — I've tried uninstalling the `apt` version and using `snap` as suggested in a comment, but that gets me nowhere. The `snap install` seems to work, and *something* ends up in `/snap/sublime-text`, but there is no apparent way to run it. In fact nothing I've read about how the whole `snap` facility is supposed to work has any apparent bearing on what actually happens on my system.

*more info* — Switching to a Unity session makes Sublime (and the few other things that were affected, like `lxappearance`) work normally. Thus I think the problem has to do with something about my xfce4 setup, so I'll look into that.

Comment: From command line you can run `/snap/bin/sublime-text.subl` to run the snap version.  Chances are you don't have `/snap/bin` in your path.

Comment: Well lots of `snap` documents say it "automatically" fixes the `PATH` but that does not seem to be borne out by actual trials.

Comment: Probably fixes it when you either reboot, logout and log back in, or relaunch the terminal.

Comment: Directly running `/snap/bin/subl` does nothing; no error is reported but nothing happens. The file is a symlink to `/snap/bin/sublime-text.subl`, which is in turn a link to `/usr/bin/snap`.

Comment: Did you not read my first comment, the command line is `/snap/bin/sublime-text.subl` to get it to run.  Just paste that into a terminal.

Comment: `/snap/bin/subl` is a symlink to `/snap/bin/sublime-text.subl`. Directly running the latter does the same nothing as `/snap/bin/subl`.

Comment: I don't know what you have done with your system.  It works fine for me with removing and installing.  I do not have a license for the developers edition so I am absolutely no help there.  But those are the commands I run, or I run just `sublime-text.subl` from a terminal window and it comes up for me.  Maybe reboot your computer.  Maybe try reinstalling the snap application itself, `sudo apt install --reinstall snap`

Comment: Well it's a brand-new clean 18.04 install on a new machine, so I haven't had a chance to do much. The `apt` installation (which is what I've been doing to install and update Sublime for many years now) *does* work except for the layout issue in the menu, and that version works perfectly on my older 16.04 laptop.

Comment: If it is the apt version, try a different GTK theme.  I have been using Xfce4 for years as well and I am using 18.04.  My menus look fine, but if I change my Style to something like Lubuntu Dark Panel which I have installed as themes I can use, my menus look exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @Terrance yes that's what I strongly suspect the problem to be; I'll update the question if I figure out what it is. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a GTK theme issue. Apparently, though Ubuntu ships with lots and lots of themes to choose from, *almost all of them don't work*.  From xfce4 you get to those via the "Appearance" setting tool. One of the themes that does work is "Adwaita", and as it's not offensive that's what I ended up with.